# Mylyn & Git: How tu use Mylyn with a local git bare repository

Tags: git, mylyn

I am not able to find a connector for Mylyn to connect to a git repository I have on a Server.
Can someone please point me at the right direction?

This one seems deprecated:
- http://www.javaforge.com/project/EGIT#download

Answer (score 0):

To connect to a git repo with Eclipse you need [EGit](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide), there is no Mylyn connector for doing that. Unless you meant you want to connect to a *Gerrit* server. If that's the case have look [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Gerrit#Using_the_Mylyn_Gerrit_Connector) for an example on how to use the connector.